# How do I get the corresponding constant variable name for the integer value of -101 an Oracle SQL type from ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i)

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

How do I get the corresponding constant variable name for the integer value of an Oracle SQL type from ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i)?

Few examples of constant variables are the following:

```
        java.sql.Types.VARCHAR: 
        java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR:
        java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR:
        java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
        java.sql.Types.NUMERIC:
        java.sql.Types.SMALLINT:
        java.sql.Types.BIGINT:
        java.sql.Types.FLOAT:
        java.sql.Types.DOUBLE:
        java.sql.Types.DECIMAL:
        java.sql.Types.DATE:
        java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP:
        java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
        java.sql.Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
```

But I'm getting a value of -101 for a specific column which is TIMESTAMP WITH TZ. I'm using Oracle by the way.

So, given the value of -101, what is the constant variable should I use for this? I can see that there's something like oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ but it's not an integer but an actual type.

I tried search the entire java.sql.Types and I couldn't find a match for -101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a misunderstood between the JDBC specification and the Oracle driver's implementation.

[There is an old bug related to this same question on Squirrel's Backlog](https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/700/).

To discover which constant in `java.sql.Types` is related to a specific integer value, you can use reflection and loop over all constants and find the one who matches.

But in your case, you'll need a work around to translate the - 101 returned by the oracle driver to the 2014 value specified on the `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` constant.